# How can I download a file to a specific directory?

Tags: python, download, dir

I have been recently trying to make a program in python that downloads files to a specific directory. I am using Ubuntu and so far i have this

```
import os
import getpass
import urllib2

y = getpass.getuser()

if not os.access('/home/' + y + '/newdir/', os.F_OK):
    print("Making New Directory")
    os.mkdir('/home/' + y + '/newdir/')

url = ("http://example.com/Examplefile.ex")
file_name = url.split('/')[-1]
u = urllib2.urlopen(url)
f = open(file_name, 'wb')
meta = u.info()
file_size = int(meta.getheaders("Content-Length")[0])
print "Downloading: %s Bytes: %s" % (file_name, file_size)

file_size_dl = 0
block_sz = 8192
while True:
    buffer = u.read(block_sz)
    if not buffer:
    break

    file_size_dl += len(buffer)
    f.write(buffer)
    status = r"%10d  [%3.2f%%]" % (file_size_dl, file_size_dl * 100. / file_size)
    status = status + chr(8)*(len(status)+1)
    print status,

f.close()
```

this currently downloads the file to the same directory how could I change the directory it downloads to?

fixed it new code:

```
import os
import getpass
import urllib2

y = getpass.getuser()

if not os.access('/home/' + y + '/newdir/', os.F_OK):
    print("Making New Directory")
    os.mkdir('/home/' + y + '/newdir/')

os.chdir('/home/'+y+'/newdir/')

url = ("http://example.com/Examplefile.ex")
file_name = url.split('/')[-1]
u = urllib2.urlopen(url)
f = open(file_name, 'wb')
meta = u.info()
file_size = int(meta.getheaders("Content-Length")[0])
print "Downloading: %s Bytes: %s" % (file_name, file_size)

file_size_dl = 0
block_sz = 8192
while True:
    buffer = u.read(block_sz)
    if not buffer:
    break

    file_size_dl += len(buffer)
    f.write(buffer)
    status = r"%10d  [%3.2f%%]" % (file_size_dl, file_size_dl * 100. / file_size)
    status = status + chr(8)*(len(status)+1)
    print status,

f.close()
```

Comment: You could change the `file_name` to be say `'/home/%s/newdir/%s' % (y,url.split('/')[-1])` ?

Comment: mathematical.coffee now that gives me an error with the u variable

Comment: `u` has nothing to do with `f`, so I don't see how that's happening. My suggestion is the same as @IgnaciaVazquez-Abrams -- in your `open(file_name,'wb')` you just need to have `file_name` include the directory you want to save to (so `file_name` is (say) `/home/foo/Example.ex` as opposed to `Example.ex`). The code snippet I gave was one way to modify `file_name`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry Guys I was Being stupid but to Answer the Question I added

```
os.chdir('/home/' + y + '/newdir/')
```

right after the first if statement ex:

```
import os
import getpass
import urllib2

y = getpass.getuser()

if not os.access('/home/' + y + '/newdir/', os.F_OK):
    print("Making New Directory")
    os.mkdir('/home/' + y + '/newdir/')

os.chdir('/home/'+y+'/newdir/')

url = ("http://example.com/Examplefile.ex")
file_name = url.split('/')[-1]
u = urllib2.urlopen(url)
f = open(file_name, 'wb')
meta = u.info()
file_size = int(meta.getheaders("Content-Length")[0])
print "Downloading: %s Bytes: %s" % (file_name, file_size)

file_size_dl = 0
block_sz = 8192
while True:
    buffer = u.read(block_sz)
    if not buffer:
    break

    file_size_dl += len(buffer)
    f.write(buffer)
    status = r"%10d  [%3.2f%%]" % (file_size_dl, file_size_dl * 100. / file_size)
    status = status + chr(8)*(len(status)+1)
    print status,

f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass the directory to `open()` in the filename.

Comment: and how would i pass the directory?

Comment: Same way you passed the filename. Especially since it's part of the filename.

Answer (score 0):

Use [os.path.join](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.join%20os.path.join) to add the directory to `file_name`:

```
    from os.path import join

    directory = join('/home/', y, '/newdir/')
    # You can now use directory everywhere you used to build the directory name

    # and then, later in the script:
    file_name = url.split('/')[-1]
    file_name = join(directory, file_name)
```