# How to download to a specific directory?

Tags: python

This is how I'm downloading:

```
    webbrowser.open(download_url)
```

So I've got the URL and I'm just opening it with the `webbrowser` module. This downloads whatever is on the other side of that URL to the default download location of my default browser.

How can I change this location to something I specify in my program? I feel like this should have a simple solution but I can't find anything about it on the web. I tried `os.chdir()` and that had no effect.

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9628770/how-can-i-download-a-file-to-a-specific-directory

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [`urllib.urlretrieve`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlretrieve) ([`urllib.request.urlretrieve`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlretrieve) in Python 3.x):

```
import urllib

urllib.urlretrieve('http://example.com/file.ext', '/path/to/directory/filename.ext')
```

**NOTE** the second argument should be file path, not directory path.

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlretrieve

Use This :

```
import urllib
urllib.urlretrieve('http://python.org/images/python-logo.gif', '/tmp/foo.gif')
```

Answer (score 0):

You should list or get all files from that directory by using `.read()` function

```
import urllib

dirpath = 'http://www.sitesomehting.com/directory/'

url = urlopen(dirpath)

str = url.read().decode('utf-8')

pattern = re.compile('*.*')

files = pattern.findall(str)
```

Then you can get these files in that directory one by one using urlretrieve

```
for file in files:
    urllib.urlretrieve(dirpath + file, localfilelocation)
```

Please note this is untested code and mainly a logic on how you can solve the problem.

Also this is one [link](http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/131960-get-directory-http-web-site) with `BeautifulSoup` and `urllib`.