# How can the download directory be set?

Tags: python

I am trying to download a url to a specific file. I have this many files to download which require for me to access the download url one by one. this code helps me

```
try:
   filename='document/downloadedFile/'
   os.system("open \"\" "+downloandurl)
   print(downloandurl, "File Downloaded")
except Exception as e:
     print(e)
```

This is a [sample](http://%20https://dibbs2.bsm.dla.mil/Downloads/Awards/18SEP19/SP330018A5010SP330019F1182.PDF) url. Once the url is open a pdf file is downloaded. Everything works fine but the file is downloaded by default to Download directory. I want it to be downloaded to a folder in the directory the code is running from. How do I change the download directory?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21018612/how-to-download-to-a-specific-directory-with-python

Comment: Please don't tag your question with unrelated tags.