# urllib: specifying download path makes url invalid

Tags: python, urllib, urlretrieve

I am trying to write a function that takes a url and a path and downloads a file to that path IF it's a text file.

```
import urllib
import re
import os


mcBethURL = 'https://ia802707.us.archive.org/1/items/macbeth02264gut/0ws3410.txt'

def  download_file(url, path, local_filename):
    try:
        url_type = urllib.request.urlopen(url).info()['content-type']
        if bool(re.search('t[e]*xt', url_type)):
            local_filename = url.split('/')[-1]
            location = os.path.join("/{}/{}".format(path, local_filename))
            urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, path, filename=local_filename)
        else:
            print('No text file found at given URL, download aborted!')
    # some more exceptions here yet not relevant
    except:
        print('invalid url')

download_file(mcBethURL, '/home/wilma/PycharmProjects/Uni', 'mcBeth')
```

`urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, path, filename=local_filename)` doesn't work since it prints `invalid url` yet `urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, filename=local_filename)` works yet I can not specify a path. I inserted the path parameter looking at [How to download to a specific directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21018612/how-to-download-to-a-specific-directory)

Do have an idea why I can not urlretrieve specifying a path variable and a name for the file in which the download should be saved in?

Comment: The problem is that your code prints "invalid url" for **any exception**, even if the exception didn't have anything to do with the url...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So looking at this [What command to use instead of urllib.request.urlretrieve?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15035123/what-command-to-use-instead-of-urllib-request-urlretrieve) it looks like `urllib.request.urlretrieve` is on the outs and you might consider using `shutil.copyfileobj` or  `requests.get`. From looking at the docs. This example seems relevant for the legacy interface you are using.

```
import urllib.request
local_filename, headers = urllib.request.urlretrieve('http://python.org/')
html = open(local_filename)
html.close()
```

In [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#legacy-interface) `urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, filename=None, reporthook=None, data=None)` does not have a second positional argument so it is being ignored in your code.

Comment: Thanks! How bad is it to use `urllib.request.urlretrieve`? I joined `path` and `local_filename` and used this for the path parameter and it created the file in the specified path.